# how to write the value into the excel taken from the front end UI Application in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am using the below code for reading the value from the UI:

```
String strwebref = driver.findElement(By.id("applstatusframe")).getAttribute("src");
        String[] strRef = strwebref.split("=");
        String[] str = strRef[3].split("&");
        String finalRefr = str[0];
```

The value i want to store is now in variable `finalRef`.
Now I am writing the function for writing that value into the cells of the excel sheet:

```
File fl = new File("C:\\Workspace\\Proj_UAP\\Datatables\\BoscoRequester.xls");

WritableWorkbook wwb;
WritableSheet wsht;
Workbook existingbook=null;

if(!fl.exists()){
    wwb=Workbook.createWorkbook(fl);
    wsht=wwb.getSheet("BoscoRequester");
} else {
    existingbook=Workbook.getWorkbook(fl);
    wwb=Workbook.createWorkbook(fl,existingbook);
    wsht=wwb.getSheet("BoscoRequester");
}

int row = 1;
int col = 1;
int i;
for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
{
    Label lbl=new Label(i,col, finalRefr);
    wsht.addCell(lbl);
    wwb.write();
}
```

Here the code: `wsht.addCell(lbl)` does not work for me.

Comment: Why does it not work?

Answer (score 0):

What error your getting? or it's just not writing into excel

also you can try in this way:

```
  public void setValueIntoCell(String strSheetName,int iColumnNumber, int     

  iRowNumber,String strData) throws WriteException
{
    WritableSheet wshTemp = wwbCopy.getSheet(strSheetName);
    Label labTemp = new Label(iColumnNumber, iRowNumber, strData);

    try {
        wshTemp.addCell(labTemp);
         } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

    wsht.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 1, "PASS");
    wsht.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 2, "FAIL");
    wsht.setValueIntoCell("sheet1", 5, 3, "PASS");
```